# How to execute a Java class as CGI script

Tags: java, class, cgi

I'm not sure if at all it is possible or not. Can I execute a Java class as CGI script, if JRE is installed and configured on the server computer?
If yes then how? Please share some references.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it will most likely be too slow to be interesting for actual production use.

CGI was originally designed to launch an external program for every invocation, which quickly proved to be much too slow for busy scripts.  For JVM's this would probably be true too, but sure you can do it.

You can access environment variables with the `System.getEnv()` call, and you can output the result with `System.out.println()`.  Remember to first print headers, then a blank line and then the actual response.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined [here](http://www.eli.sdsu.edu/courses/spring97/cs596/notes/cgiJava/cgiJava.html), it is possible to do so. But since CGI requires access to environment variables, which Java can't access, you need to do some trickery with shell scripts to make them available. Check the link for details.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm still going though it. By the way, do you know a Windows based Solution, probably which works seamlessly on XAMPP server?

Comment: Java has been able to access environment variables again since 1.4 or 1.5.